# When using Show instead of Push, which is deprecated, with UINavigationController, the VC being shown doesn't have navigationItem

Tags: ios, xcode, uinavigationcontroller, xcode6, storyboard

Alright, here is the deal.

I have a UINavigationController which has a root VC. From this root VC, you can show another VC, and from there, another, and from there, another.

The problem is that I'm running into what I think is a bug in Xcode.

In the below image, you see a button in my rootVC navigationItem that I use to segue with Show to display the second VC. You can clearly see the Navigation Bar, but when I try to drag a UIBarButtonItem into it, I can't and the reason is because if you look at the menu on the left, you'll see that there isn't a Navigation Item to drag the button into!

If I instead use the segue Push to display the second VC, I get a navigationItem... but apparently Push is deprecated.

How do I mitigate this?

[image]

Edit: I guess I can just drag in a UINavigationItem into it... but I really don't know if I should. Would there be an empty UINavigationItem underneath that that I just don't see in storyboard but is actually there?

Answer (score 1):

The navigation item is not created automatically on the second view controller, you're right.  Drag a new navigation item into the second viewcontroller's bar, and you should be good to go.

Comment: Yeah, I figured that might be the best option. I was just afraid there might be a phantom UINavigationItem underneath it, but whatever.